# Slide multiple divs to side as one

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I am trying to make navigation bar displayed in a line. For the sake of question I have created [this](http://jsfiddle.net/U7dhB/4/) fiddle. I would like to hide the red `divs` as one `div` to one side by clicking on the black `div`. So I put all the red `divs` into one `<div class="box"></div>` and tried to slide the box `div`. But it messes up. Instead of going to a side like a train it expands to multiple rows and then hides. Also I could just slide the `divs` of class `slide` but then it looks like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/U7dhB/5/). Which is not what I want, because it hides each one on its own.

Comment: you want  http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/U7dhB/8/ ?

Comment: No, that is not what I want. I want the red `divs` to hide like e.g. train going into tunnel. That is all of them are moving towards one side, but only one at a time is hiding

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you
[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/f652b/)

js:

```
state = true;
$('.clickMe').click(function () {
    if (state) {
        $("#inner").animate({
            left: '-100px'
        }, "slow");
        state = false;
    } else {
        $("#inner").animate({
            left: '0px'
        }, "slow");
        state = true;
    }

});
```

html:

```
<div class="clickMe"></div>
<div id="outer">
    <div id="inner">
        <div class="slide"></div>
        <div class="slide"></div>
        <div class="slide"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks it works nicely. Could I have a further question? I have edited a bit the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f652b/1/). Not it is a inline menu. I would like to click on `Home` and by clicking it the red `divs` would push the `Home` button aside. By clicking `Home` again the red `divs` would hide again.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/BrP2n/  . i would recommend you to research on jQuery and css a bit more before asking here.